# How to get and save CSS properties from Rails

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails

I want to store the css property of the region when I click on a colored region in Rails.

My current code gets the color property of the area, but I can not store it anywhere.

**I would like to save the color property from the click event to the DB.**

**view.html.erb**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".scale-up-center").click(function() {
        var color = $(".scale-up-center").css("background-color");
        $(".first_scale").css("background-color", color);
    })
})
```

> Code that changes background-color of first_scale when scale-up-center
>   is clicked

**view.scss**

```
background:linear-gradient(to bottom right, #8B4513, #383737);
```

> How do I get the css property of the above code?

My Rails also has coffee installed. I want to use the js code together while maintaining the coffee file. What should I do?

Comment: That is possible. You need to do Ajax to post the data to your backend, and save it.

Comment: you'll have a lot of down votes if you don't include code in your question, you need to post what you have tried, an idea at least.

Comment: Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have corrected my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".scale-up-center").click(function() {
var color = $(".scale-up-center").css("background-color");
$(".first_scale").css("background-color", color);

var formData = new FormData();

formData.append('color', color);

$.ajax({
      url: "/save/color",
      type: 'POST',
      data: formData,
      success: function (data) {
          console.log(data);
      }
};
});
```

And you need a route, a controller, an action, and a model to save the data...
If you don't know how to do this, rails guides is a good start point.